# connect to a play-with-docker instance via putty

Tags: docker, ssh, putty, ssh-keys

i'm trying to connect via putty to a play with docker instance https://labs.play-with-docker.com/

i've tried:

`ip172-18-0-21-bgnsch0v0j3g00931g9g@direct.labs.play-with-docker.com   port 22`

ERROR: disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)

`172-18-0-21-bgnsch0v0j3g00931g9g@direct.labs.play-with-docker.com     port 22`
ERROR: disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)

```
ip172-18-0-21-bgnsch0v0j3g00931g9g@direct.labs.play-with-docker.com   port 1020
```

ERROR: nothing/black terminal --> timeout

`172-18-0-21-bgnsch0v0j3g00931g9g@direct.labs.play-with-docker.com     port 1020`

ERROR: 
nothing/black terminal --> timeout

i followed this article: https://medium.com/@marcosnils/pwd-ssh-c12080ea11d1

I'm not so good with putty and ssh in general,
do i need to set some other options in putty or i'm doing somethi wrong?
No Keys to set with this service?

Comment: If it has been solved, please accept the solution.

Answer (score 9):

Here is the simple technique you have to follow as PWD doesn't need any private key file to access the already created session.

So you can have simply create a .pkk key or [use this one to download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12TELIVJUBlR7axfgm5NhELFwPGxemsTr/view?usp=sharing) and open it in putty under **Connection>SSH>Authentication**.

And simple use your ssh ip172-18-0-36-bt5urvaosm4g00efljfg@direct.labs.play-with-docker.com and open the session.

[PUTTY SETUP SCREEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNuyL.png)

[SSH LINK IN PUTTY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGf2N.png)

You will be connected.

[CONNECTION ESTABLISHED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5jKQ.png)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create a random private key with Puttygen:

1. Open puttygen and click on "Generate" button
   [image: Image1]
2. Move the mouse randomly to generate the key
   [image]
3. Once generated, click on "Save private key" button and name it as you wish.
   If you want you can also use a passphrase to protect it (not mandatory)
   [image]
4. Open a putty session, paste the ssh address of your session in the Host name textbox
   [image]
5. Add your generated ppk in "Connection->SSH->Auth" clicking on "Browse" button
   [image]
6. Click on open, happy docker!
   [image]