# Cannot connect to instance in Docker Playground via SSH

Tags: docker, ssh

I'm trying to connect to a Docker Playground instance from a SSH session initiated in CMD from my Windows 10 computer with the following command:

```
ssh -v ip172-18-0-18-cbepm33cukq00090gvu0@direct.labs.play-with-docker.com
```

Here is the SSH output:

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Connecting to direct.labs.play-with-docker.com [40.76.55.146] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Marciano/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Marciano/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Marciano/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Marciano/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Marciano/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Marciano/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Marciano/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Marciano/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Marciano/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Marciano/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version Go
debug1: no match: Go
debug1: Authenticating to direct.labs.play-with-docker.com:22 as 'ip172-18-0-18-cbepm33cukq00090gvu0'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:UyqFRi42lglohSOPKn6Hh9M83Y5Ic9IQn1PTHYqOjEA
debug1: Host 'direct.labs.play-with-docker.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\Marciano/.ssh/known_hosts:19
debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Marciano/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:/p+cVcQBROp4X3eq1wi10tfgBSVUmKDaV2/hpxNTzM0 agent
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Marciano/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:BZFw2ybMWiH6PSOug+zBT90LhgwoxDMR0Ci7wAeJs/I
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Marciano/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Marciano/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Marciano/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\Marciano/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:/p+cVcQBROp4X3eq1wi10tfgBSVUmKDaV2/hpxNTzM0 agent
debug1: Server accepts key: C:\\Users\\Marciano/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:/p+cVcQBROp4X3eq1wi10tfgBSVUmKDaV2/hpxNTzM0 agent
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to direct.labs.play-with-docker.com ([40.76.55.146]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT is supported. Reading the VTSequence from console
debug1: ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING is supported. Console supports the ansi parsing
Connecting to 52.188.151.184:8022
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to direct.labs.play-with-docker.com closed.
Transferred: sent 2212, received 1436 bytes, in 1.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 1985.7, received 1289.1
debug1: Exit status -1
```

The logs show that after successful authentication the connection is immediately closed and the process exits with -1 status.

I also tried connecting with a PUTTY client and a custom .pkk file created by me with puttygen.exe as suggested in [connect to a play-with-docker instance via putty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54046382/connect-to-a-play-with-docker-instance-via-putty) however the SSH connection failed with **Server refused to allocate pty** status.

```
=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~= PuTTY log 2022.07.24 17:13:47 =~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=
Using username "ip172-18-0-18-cbepm33cukq00090gvu0".
Authenticating with public key "rsa-key-20220724"
Connecting to 52.188.151.184:8022
Server refused to allocate pty
```

Below is the more detailed output generated with -vvv `ssh -vvv ip172-18-0-18-cbepm33cukq00090gvu0@direct.labs.play-with-docker.com`

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Marciano/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolving "direct.labs.play-with-docker.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to direct.labs.play-with-docker.com [40.76.55.146] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Marciano/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Marciano/.ssh/id_rsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Marciano/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Marciano/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Marciano/.ssh/id_dsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Marciano/.ssh/id_dsa.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Marciano/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Marciano/.ssh/id_dsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Marciano/.ssh/id_dsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Marciano/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Marciano/.ssh/id_ecdsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Marciano/.ssh/id_ecdsa.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Marciano/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Marciano/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Marciano/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Marciano/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Marciano/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Marciano/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Marciano/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Marciano/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Marciano/.ssh/id_xmss error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Marciano/.ssh/id_xmss.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Marciano/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Marciano/.ssh/id_xmss-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Marciano/.ssh/id_xmss-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\Marciano/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version Go
debug1: no match: Go
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to direct.labs.play-with-docker.com:22 as 'ip172-18-0-18-cbepm33cukq00090gvu0'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\Marciano/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file C:\\Users\\Marciano/.ssh/known_hosts:19
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from direct.labs.play-with-docker.com
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Marciano/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96
debug2: compression ctos: none
debug2: compression stoc: none
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:UyqFRi42lglohSOPKn6Hh9M83Y5Ic9IQn1PTHYqOjEA
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\Marciano/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file C:\\Users\\Marciano/.ssh/known_hosts:19
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from direct.labs.play-with-docker.com
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Marciano/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\Marciano/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file C:\\Users\\Marciano/.ssh/known_hosts:19
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 40.76.55.146
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Marciano/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug1: Host 'direct.labs.play-with-docker.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\Marciano/.ssh/known_hosts:19
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Marciano/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:/p+cVcQBROp4X3eq1wi10tfgBSVUmKDaV2/hpxNTzM0 agent
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Marciano/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:BZFw2ybMWiH6PSOug+zBT90LhgwoxDMR0Ci7wAeJs/I
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Marciano/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Marciano/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Marciano/.ssh/id_xmss
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\Marciano/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:/p+cVcQBROp4X3eq1wi10tfgBSVUmKDaV2/hpxNTzM0 agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: C:\\Users\\Marciano/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:/p+cVcQBROp4X3eq1wi10tfgBSVUmKDaV2/hpxNTzM0 agent
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: ED25519 SHA256:/p+cVcQBROp4X3eq1wi10tfgBSVUmKDaV2/hpxNTzM0
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using ssh-ed25519
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to direct.labs.play-with-docker.com ([40.76.55.146]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT is supported. Reading the VTSequence from console
debug3: This windows OS supports conpty
debug1: ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING is supported. Console supports the ansi parsing
debug3: Successfully set console output code page from:65001 to 65001
debug3: Successfully set console input code page from:850 to 65001
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 2097152 rmax 32768
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 35
Connecting to 52.188.151.184:8022
debug2: channel 0: written 35 to efd 6
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_read (i0 o1 sock -1 wfd 4 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_write (i3 o1 sock -1 wfd 5 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug3: Successfully set console output code page from 65001 to 65001
debug3: Successfully set console input code page from 65001 to 850
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 e[write]/0 fd -1/-1/6 sock -1 cc -1)

debug3: send packet: type 1
debug3: Successfully set console output code page from 65001 to 65001
debug3: Successfully set console input code page from 65001 to 850
Connection to direct.labs.play-with-docker.com closed.
Transferred: sent 2212, received 1436 bytes, in 1.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 1964.8, received 1275.5
debug1: Exit status -1
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was not able to connect.

- The log indicates there is a mismatch in the public key algorithim

```
debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/thiru/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:okCget2rl5sGoR024BKQkKZrv/7lwc/CZ98bDmECvF8
debug1: send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm
```

- check the PWD (play with docker) instance algorithm, navigate to the Docker playground and check the .ssh algorithm type in my case it was `ed25519` not rsa.

[image]

To fix this from Git bash terminal, I had to create a new ssh key with ed25519

```
$ ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -P "" -f ~/.ssh/id_ed25519

Generating public/private ed25519 key pair.
Your identification has been saved in /c/Users/thiru/.ssh/id_ed25519
Your public key has been saved in /c/Users/thiru/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
```

- Then I was able to connect to the PWD instance

[image]

- complete Ssh client log

```
 ssh -v ip17212-***********@direct.labs.play-with-docker.com
OpenSSH_8.8p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to direct.labs.play-with-docker.com [40.*.*.146] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
...
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version Go
debug1: compat_banner: no match: Go
debug1: Authenticating to direct.labs.play-with-docker.com:22 as 'ip172-****-*********'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /c/Users/thiru/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:vCb*******************
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /c/Users/thiru/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'direct.labs.play-with-docker.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/thiru/.ssh/known_hosts:8
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/thiru/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:okCget2rl5sGoR024BKQkKZrv/7lwc/CZ98bDmECvF8
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/thiru/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/thiru/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/thiru/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/thiru/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/thiru/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/thiru/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/thiru/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:okCget2rl5sGoR024BKQkKZrv/7lwc/CZ98bDmECvF8
debug1: send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/thiru/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/thiru/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/thiru/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/thiru/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/thiru/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/thiru/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
ip172-1*****2-cd5d********g@direct.labs.play-with-docker.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: I don't quite understand how SSH works in this case. Why does locally generated key work, without copying the newly generated public key into the docker playground?